# Disable process id showing in Syslog-ng logs

Tags: centos7, syslog-ng, logparser

I configured **syslog-ng** (**version 3.21.1**) on a CentOS7 server and found that logs are in following format.

```
Aug 26 12:59:28 xyz74hd.com radiusd[20142]: 92djvd4654654164nadskj795234dc Reason: pldap: Forind credentials incorrect: Invalid credentials possible
```

I do not require Process-ID (in above log **[20142]**) in my logs. Thus required syslog-format should be as follows:

```
Aug 26 12:59:28 xyz74hd.com radiusd: 92djvd4654654164nadskj795234dc Reason: pldap: Forind credentials incorrect: Invalid credentials possible
```

Before, I was using **CentOS6** with older syslog-ng version (**3.2.5**). But as I deployed **CentOS7** with one of latest syslog-ng verion(3.21.1) the error occurs. (syslog-ng configurations are almost same)

On my new deployment I am getting the additional field of Process-ID in logs due to which log-parser are behaving absurd. I can not change code.

Is there any solution on syslog-ng level so that I can get rid off these process IDs in my logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to get rid of the process ID:

- you can create a template for your destination to use a custom output format, for example:

  `file("/var/log/messages" template("$DATE $HOST $PROGRAM: $MESSAGE\n"))`
- you can add a rewrite rule before your destination, where you unset PID:

  `rewrite { unset(value("PID")); };`

  or

  `rewrite { set("" value("PID")); };`

Comment: If you want to use a rewrite rule, please choose the second one until `unset` is fixed (v3.24.1): https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng/pull/2896